# Changing a VM Network Security Group from Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to change the network security group in a VM, from azure portal.
From azure portal and going to Networking, I can see the actual network security group ("mygroup1"). I want to change it to "mygroup2".

If I press the Network security group name I can navigate to the azure portal but I cannot see the way to change the actual Network security group from my VM to a new existing one.

EDIT: The VM is connected. I suspect to do this I also have to shut it down I guess.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the network security group in a VM, instead:

- You can associate a network security group to, or dissociate a network security group from a network interface.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface#associate-or-dissociate-a-network-security-group

1. In the search box at the top of the portal, enter network interfaces in the search box. When network interfaces appear in the search results, select it.
2. Select the network interface in the list that you want to associate a network security group to, or dissociate a network security group from.
3. Select Network security group under SETTINGS.
4. Select Edit.
5. Select Network security group and then select the network security group you want to associate to the network interface, or select None, to dissociate a network security group. Save

- You can Associate a network security group to, or dissociate a network security group from a subnet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-subnet#change-subnet-settings

1. Go to the Azure portal to view your virtual networks. Search for and select Virtual networks.
2. Select the name of the virtual network containing the subnet you want to change.
3. From Settings, select Subnets.
4. In the list of subnets, select the subnet you want to change settings for.
5. In the subnet page, change any of the following settings: Network security group
6. Click Save